# How do I get this for loop to print

Tags: python, for-loop

Would any happen to know why I keep getting the error below in my for loop?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated and helpful.

```
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for number in the_count:
print(f"This is count {number}")

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e3d6b461f13e> in <module>
----> 1 print(f"This is count {number}")

NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

Comment: The error message says the `print()` statement is on line 1, which does not match the posted code.  Are you _sure_ this is your actual code?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Either I get an IndentationError or with the indentation fixed it works. Interestingly your third line shows up as `1` in the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this line by line in a terminal or as a .py file? This code works perfectly if you run it as a python file.

```
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for number in the_count:
    print(f"This is count {number}")
```

Which outputs:

```
This is count 1
This is count 2
This is count 3
This is count 4
This is count 5
```

You may run into errors with the for loop if you run this code line by line, since the for loop would be executed fully prior to even reading the print statment.

Comment: I was running nthe code line by line in Jupiter Notebook.  So do you think it will work if I try it the way you just executed the code by using one line instead of line by line?  Thank you very much for your help by the way.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.  I am excited to try this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I am very grateful!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well it should give indentation error but it’s giving name error

```py
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for number in the_count:
    print(f"This is count {number}")
```

This is how your code should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways you can print the loop:

```
# Option 1
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for x in the_count:
    print('This is count:' + str(x))

# Option 2
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for x in the_count:
    print(f"This is count {x}")
```